# Detecting EOT from stdin in PHP

Tags: php, stdin

Seems like a really simple task, but I am having a really hard time identifying the end of input fed via stdin to PHP [5.5.x]. Instead of passing a `0x04` EOT character to cap the final string, `fgets(STDIN)` seems to decide to stop waiting for input with no discernable signal. The most obvious demonstration is through the code:

```
<?php
while(substr(rtrim(fgets(STDIN), PHP_EOL), -1) != 0x04) {
    echo "Input received.";
}
```

After <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, the loop tightens immediately and repeated "Input received." spills into stdout instead of detecting the EOT or waiting for further input. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: Both

1. passing `\x04` via pipe and comparing against the `0x04` literal, and
2. passing `\u0004` [using NodeJS's `child_process`] and comparing against an EOT character created by `mb_convert_encoding('&#x0004;', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES')`

succeed and allow the program to terminate. Applying the latter comparison to `\x04` has the same effect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> used to and continues to have.